# Mongoose and Typescript. Using this in ref

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm currently facing a problem converting my JS-App to Typescript. I have a Schema similar to this

```
const UserGroupSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    Name : {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    Users : [{
        type : ObjectId,
        ref : UserModel.modelName
    }],
    UserGroups: [{
        type: ObjectId,
        ref : this
    }]
});
```

now using ref : this in UserGroups obviously creates a problem in TypeScript and the linter gives me the following error

> [ts] 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.

do you have any idea how I could make this work in TypeScript?  I know I could just directly use tha modelName here, but I want to define that in the model file. And I wont be able to import the model file here as this would create a circular reference.

Comment: of course you could always add `"noImplicitThis": true` to your `tsconfig.json` or amend mongoose typings for `Schema`

Comment: I don't think this code will work as you intend even in JavaScript: there is no `this` object available, except perhaps the global object.  What object did you intend to refer to?

Comment: I have to admit I also stumbled over this line and was wondering. I got that this from some documentation though (will try to find it) Do you have another idea how i could self reference in a schema?